# Script fails and says unexpected token >'

Tags: shell-script, centos, openstack

While running the following script, I get the errors. How to solve this?

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 # Show colored output if running interactively
  3 if [ -t 1 ] ; then
  4     export ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true
  5 fi
  6 # Log everything from this script into _quickstart.log
  7 echo "$0 $@" > _quickstart.log
  8 exec &> >(tee -i -a _quickstart.log )
  9 # With LANG set to everything else than C completely undercipherable errors
 10 # like "file not found" and decoding errors will start to appear during scripts
 11 # or even ansible modules
 12 LANG=C

[root@localhost quickstart_images]# sh quickstart.sh -u file:///usr/share/quickstart_images/undercloud-mitaka.qcow2 localhost
quickstart.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
quickstart.sh: line 8: `exec &> >(tee -i -a _quickstart.log )'
[root@localhost quickstart_images]#
```

Comment: Your script mention ` bash` as an interpreter do not try to use it with sh. Try to execute your script with `bash -x`

Comment: bash quickstart.sh file:///usr/share/quickstart_images/undercloud-mitaka.qcow2 localhost      This one worked.

Answer (score 2):

**First**: instead of running your `bash` script using `sh` make it execute-able:

```
chmod +x quickstart.sh
```

And execute it by its own:

```
./quickstart.sh -u file:///usr/share/quickstart_images/undercloud-mitaka.qcow2 localhost
```

**Second**: It seems like you have a problem in your bash script:

Running your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ reported the following error in the script:

```
Line 7:
echo "$0 $@" > _quickstart.log
         ^-- SC2145: Argument mixes string and array. Use * or separate argument.
```

The problem you are facing is **mixing** *string* and *array*.

You can solve the problem using one of the following methods:

1. Avoid the mix between string and array by separating the arguments using two different quotes:

   ```
   echo "$0" "$@" > _quickstart.log
   ```

Or

2. Replacing `$@` with `$*` which replace the array with a string

   ```
   echo "$0 $*" > _quickstart.log
   ```

Note the differences between `$@` and `$*`:

[Bash Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters)

> `($*)` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter
>   expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those
>   words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion.
>   **When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single
>   word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character
>   of the IFS special variable**. **That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…"**,
>   where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If
>   IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null,
>   the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> `($@)` Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. **When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2"** …. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).